# Which physicist is this quote attributed to?

Tags: physics, quantum-mechanics, quote

There is a quote from a 19-20th century scientist that goes (and I am paraphrasing):

> New scientific theories are never accepted until old scientist die.

Who is this cynical quote attributed to, and what is the exact phrasing of the quote?

Based on my memory of the quote I would put the following odds:

- 90% it was a physicist from the late 19 or early 20th century
- 70% it was Niels Bohr or Erwin Schrodinger — I did of course google for a list of known quotes but didn’t see the above one anywhere.
- 20% it was in reference to quantum mechanics.

Comment: The quote I've heard, attributed to Planck, is: `science progresses one funeral at a time`!

Comment: I would like to add that this statement is not only cynical, but also incorrect. It is a huge exaggeration.

Comment: @terdon  fair enough.  comment removed

Comment: @CarlWitthoft thank you kindly. Mine as well.

Comment: Also see [Belief Perseverance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Belief_perseverance), which is what Planck was observing or commenting. There are lots of example of it, like rejecting heliocentrism for 1800 years or accepting password blanking today (password blanking needs to go away).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Max Planck, [*Scientific Autobiography and Other Papers*](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=7213) (Westport, CT: Greenwood, 1949), [pp. 33-34](https://books.google.com/books?id=F3iMBAAAQBAJ&pg=PT24):

> A new scientific truth does not triumph by convincing its opponents and making them see the light, but rather because its opponents eventually die, and a new generation grows up that is familiar with it.

<sup>as quoted in:
• M. López Corredoira and C. Castro Perelman, [*Against the Tide: A Critical Review by Scientists of How Physics and Astronomy Get Done*](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=5032) (Boca Raton, Fla.: Universal Publishers, 2008), p. 12
or
• Peter Pesic, [*Music and the Making of Modern Science*](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=5685) (MIT Press, 2014), p. 265.</sup>

Comment: Wonder if this was first published in German. The '49 edition was translated from German.

Comment: @MaxW Yes, in 1948: M. Planck, [_Wissenschaftliche Selbstbiographie_](http://library.vetmed.fu-berlin.de/digbib/Planck/&checksum=1defc216ddb3825bb0705f07cd835da0&title=&linktype=digitalObject&detail=). Leipzig 1948. (PAV, Bd. 3, S. 374–401): « Eine neue wissenschaftliche Wahrheit pflegt sich nicht in der Weise durchzusetzen, dass ihre Gegner überzeugt werden und sich als belehrt erklären, sondern vielmehr dadurch, dass ihre Gegner allmählich aussterben und dass die heranwachsende Generation von vornherein mit der Wahrheit vertraut gemacht ist. »

Comment: @ Geremia, Is this machine translation good (DeepL.com)? "A new scientific truth does not assert itself in such a way that its opponents are persuaded and declare themselves instructed, but rather by the fact that its opponents gradually die out and that the growing generation is familiar with the truth from the outset."

Comment: @M.Farooq I'm not that good at German to know, but cf. [this question on German StackExchange](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/52585/11197).

Comment: That forum is not for translations. I was explicitly told once because I often ask questions there. That is for language related questions. DeepL is pretty good. I have written one article on the DeepL German translation for chemistry related papers with the help of a German co-author.

Comment: The machine forgot to translate "pflegt sich": "does not USUALLY assert itself..."

Answer (score 2):

> 90% it was a physicist from the late 19 or early 20th century

Excellent memory! It is actually from Thomas Kuhn who was a physicist, and who later turned into a philosopher. His book *The Structure of Scientific Revolution* mentions something like this on page 152. This is the third edition 1962 reprinted in 1996.

**Edits:** On page 151, he also quotes Planck.

[image: Book image]

Comment: I think it is better to attribute the articulation of this idea to Planck. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck%27s_principle.

Comment: It is likely then, but Kuhn did not credit Planck. We should see the original book first because there so many incorrectly attributed quotes to big names.

Comment: Adding the year of the book (I believe it is 1962) might help decide which answer is most correct.

Comment: **Wrong** ! See Kuhn, *SSR*, page 151 : "And Max Planck, surveying his own career in his *Scientific Autobiography*, sadly remarked that..."

Comment: @Mauro I am specifically talking about this quoted paragraph! Those are Kuhn's own words! Yes he quotes Max Planck in previous paragraphs.

Comment: But your answer does **not** mention Planck's name ... The 19th-20th Century physicist was Max Planck and not the 20th Century historian of science Thomas Kuhn.

Comment: Added it for the sake of completeness. Kuhn also had a PhD in physics.

Comment: I think it's a big stretch to claim that this paragraph is the quote from the question. It's certainly based on the same idea but attributing the quote to Kuhn is like attributing "Man cannot live by bread alone" to the authors of some government nutrition guidelines.

Comment: I agree David, given that there is a full reference to Max Planck now.